# Any flexibility with mapping UDFs in Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a very simple UDF I'll call GetNumber. It would be used in my LINQ-to-SQL queries like so:

```
var query = from a in db.TableA
            where db.GetNumber(a.Something, Configuration.Setting) == 7
            select a;
```

The second parameter is always going to be coming from a configuration setting, so I want to simplify the call to just look like this throughout the code:

```
var query = from a in db.TableA
            where db.GetNumber(a.Something) == 7
            select a;
```

...where the Configuration.Setting part is contained within the GetNumber method. Is there any way to accomplish this, or do you have to match the UDF parameters exactly with your corresponding datacontext function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this directly, but you could create an extension method that encapsulates the logic to retrieve the second parameter.